# .NET Adding object to database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to .NET. I am create a internet shop but i have a problems

My Error:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'
>
> UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the
> inner exception for details.
>
> SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'GadgetId',
> table 'GadgetStorege.dbo.Gadgets'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
> fails. The statement has been terminated.

I using 3 project in Solution I have a interface IGadgetRepository in c# Class Library Domain and using asp.net mvc in controller

```
    public interface IGadgetRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Gadget> Gadgets { get; }
    void AddGadget(Gadget gadget);
    void SaveGadget(Gadget gadget);
    void DeleteGadget(Gadget gadget);
}
```

My model:

```
public class Gadget
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int GadgetId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

I want to adding object to database:

```
     public class EFGadgetRepository : IGadgetRepository
        {
            EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();
            public IEnumerable<Gadget> Gadgets
            {
                get { return context.Gadgets; }
            }
    
            public void AddGadget(Gadget gadget)
            {
                context.Gadgets.Add(gadget);
                context.SaveChanges();
                
                int id = gadget.GadgetId;
            }
    
            public void DeleteGadget(Gadget gadget)
            {
                Gadget dbEntry = context.Gadgets.Find(gadget.GadgetId);
                context.Gadgets.Remove(dbEntry);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
}
```

My method in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string name, string type)
{
    Gadget gadget = new Gadget();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        gadget.Name = name;
        gadget.Type = type;
        repository.AddGadget(gadget);
        TempData["message"] = string.Format("Gadget add \"{0}\" gadget", gadget.Name);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(gadget);
    }
}
```

My photo errors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD71r.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KhA3.png)

I want to add object and delete object to database.
I using Entity Framewor for my project.
how can i solve this problem?

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: Add [Key] atttribute to your ID

Comment: @mjwills   version of EF 6.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: SSMS declare auto increment]

Declare an Auto-increment = 1 on your PK GadgetId in your database table using SSMS or with [Key] annotation if you're using Code firt